# How can I make this equation flat out after 1?

Tags: calculus

I want to make the equation $y=(x-1)^3+0.98$ flatten out after $x=1$ without using a piece-wise function. How can I this? [image]

Comment: What do you mean by flatten out?

Comment: "Piece-wise function" doesn't make sense. I assume you mean to avoid a piece-wise definition for the a function. Can you explain your motivation?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a particular asymptote in mind?  What changes to your function are allowed?  What you plotted is not the function you quote: $ (4-1)^3+0.98=26.98$, not $1.22$